# SQL Enrollment and Sorting Query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
Branch (branch_ID, name, address_street, address_district)
Foreign key: None

• Instructor (instructor_ID, name, year_of_experience)
Foreign key: None

• Class (class_ID, name, description, date, capacity, branch_ID, instructor_ID)
 Foreign key: 
{branch_ID} referencing Branch.branch_ID
{instructor_ID} referencing Instructor.instructor_ID

• Member (member_ID, name, date_of_birth, referrer_ID) 
 {referrer_ID} referencing Member.member_ID
```

Note: A member may be referred by none or at most one other member. A member can refer
many other members to the fitness company.

```
• Enrollment (member_ID, class_ID)
 Foreign key:
 {member_ID} referencing Member.member_ID
{class_ID} referencing Class.class_ID
```

Display the member_ID and name of the member(s) who enrolled in a class with class
name as “Water Aerobics”.
• Please sort the records in descending order of the member_ID

I used the following query but it didn't work. I receive blank when I go to display it later.

```
$query = "SELECT Member.member_ID,Member.name FROM Member WHERE Member.member_ID in (SELECT e.member_ID FROM Enrollment e WHERE e.class_ID IN (SELECT c.class_ID FROM Class c WHERE c.name='Water Aerobics%')) ORDER BY member_ID DESC";
```

I am stuck with this and would be obliged if you could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `IN()` use joins instead. Here we can use `inner join` to match rows of one table to another to form relationships from member to class

```
SELECT
      m.member_ID
    , m.name
FROM Member m
INNER JOIN Enrollment e ON m.member_ID = e.member_ID
INNER JOIN Class c ON e.class_ID = c.class_ID
WHERE c.name = 'Water Aerobics'
ORDER BY m.member_ID DESC
```

nb: When using equals for a string *don't include the % symbol*. If you wanted any result that **started** with "Water Aerobics" then you could use `c.name LIKE 'Water Aerobics%'` and this would find (for example) "Water Aerobics Level 1" & "Water Aerobics Level 2"

Comment: Still doesn't give the answer

Comment: Would you mind sharing your email so that we can have a detailed conversation?

Comment: Maybe there just isn't any data to match the wanted condition, and as I cannot see your data I cannot solve that. What happens if you leave out the where clause? and also add `, c.name` in the select clause so you can see the class name.  I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: no can do on the email address - this would make it public to the world and I just don't want that much spam that would result in global publication

Comment: Thank you. It worked with some modifications.